# @method('DELETE') and version 5.4.13

Tags: laravel

In my form index.blade, I see that my method delete() has a problem to display???

[image]

In my **index.blade** I have this:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
     <tr>
       <td> {{$student->name}}</td>
       <td> {{$student->firstname}}</td>
       <td>
       <form method="POST" action="{{ route('students.destroy', $student) }} ">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('students.edit',$student->id)}}">Editer</a>
         {{csrf_field()}}
          @method('DELETE')
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Effacer</button>
       </form>
           </td>
         </tr>
   @endforeach
```

In my Controller I have this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $students = Student::find($id);
        $students->delete();
        return redirect()->route('students.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Effacé !');
    }
```

For information, I have the version '5.4.13'.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel 5.4 you need to use

```
{{ method_field('delete') }}
```

From 5.6 `@method('delete')` is introduced.

Comment: Yes do not worry